# GeoMoose - MapServer MS4W and Postgis

Tags: postgis, shapefile, mapserver

I loaded in Postgis a number of shape files with geographical, I installed and loaded MS4W GeoMoose; I have tried several times to change the file geomoose to render my mapfile, but the result was bad, geomoose always displays a pink screen. My questions are:

1. How do I create a map file compatible with geomoose?
2. How do I connect to PostGIS geomoose?
3. What file GeoMoose must change in order to make it all work according to my needs?
4. Is there a guide on GeoMoose actually valid?

Thanks to all those who will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you'll get more responses from the Geomoose email list than Stackoverflow.

1. Have a look at the demo map files supplied with Geomoose
2. have a look at the Mapserver doc for PostGIS http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html
3. Generally you need to edit the Geomoose mapbook.xml, and create a Mapserver .map file
4. A good resource is the Geomoose doc, especially http://docs.geomoose.org/2.8/howto/layer.html

Comment: How can I sign up to the mailing list of geomoose? thank you